# How to get custom category's link?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

I have created a custom post type and custom category for that post. There are some categories in that custom category. now I want to get the links for each category I have in that list.

I just want to get the link form its tag id. how can I do that

Comment: [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Answer (score 2):

As the other's mentioned, [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) will work if you you want to do a list of things (just like `wp_list_pages` does for pages).

If you specifically want the link (URL), you can use [`get_term_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link). If you just have the term ID, it would look something like this.

```
<?php
$term_id = some_function_that_returns_term_id();
$term_link = get_term_link($term_id, 'your_custom_taxonomy');

if (!is_wp_error($term_link)) {
    // do stuff with $term_link
}
```

If you have the whole term object -- for example the object returned by [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) -- you can pass the entire object in as the first argument of `get_term_link` and you're done.

```
<?php
$term = get_term_by('id', $some_term_id, 'your_custom_taxonomy');

$term_link = false;
if ($term) {
    $term_link = get_term_link($term);
}

if (!is_wp_error($term_link)) {
    // do stuff with $term_link
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wp_list_categories('taxonomy=custom_tax');
custom_tax is custom taxonomy name